# Is there a way to check if my reactjs app was opened from cordova app?

Tags: reactjs, cordova, pdf, iframe

My problem is that the inappbrowser from cordova doesn't handle pdfs. However, in our reactjs app, we use an Iframe to display a pdf (It has it own header and branding so it's not opened as a standalone pdf):

```
return <Iframe className="h-full " src={uri} style={style} />;
```

where:

```
export function Iframe({ ...props }: IframeProps) {
  return (
    <iframe
      {...props}
      width="100%"
      height="1080"
      title={props.src}
      allowFullScreen
    ></iframe>
  );
}
```

So, I wanted to do something like, if it's being opened in cordova, do this instead:

```
<a href={Pdf} without rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank">
```

Any other suggestions would be welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can render PDFs with a couple of different JS libraries

https://viewerjs.org/

https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/

Comment: Thanks, we ended up creating out own reader using pdfjs.

Answer (score 0):

You can render different elements according to your platform which you can check with https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.3.0/cordova/device/device.platform.html. If you're using ionic it has too: https://ionicframework.com/docs/angular/platform